# ArcGIS JS api - how to hide attributes editor when new graphic is added

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, map-editor

I use ArcGIS Javascript api in 3.12 version. I have followed [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_simpletoolbar.html) in order to display editing toolbar plus template picker. It works pretty good. However I would like to hide popup window with attributes editor which is displayed after new graphic is added. That's because I already have attached to every FeatureLayer my own InfoTemplate:

```
    var template = new InfoTemplate();
    template.setTitle("Object");
    template.setContent(getPassportLink);
    var layer = new Dependencies.FeatureLayer(layers[i].serviceUrl, {
        mode : Dependencies.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        infoTemplate : template,
        outFields : [ "*" ],
    });
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to suppress popups while editing a particular layer, set `disableAttributeUpdate = true` in the corresponding layerInfo when instantiating the widget.

This is mentioned in the [API reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/editor-amd.html) in the 'Constructor Details' section.